# Defining a container to have a width of it's display:inline-block children that are wrapping

Tags: html, css

In my HTML (see http://jsfiddle.net/jg469u36/1/) I have a `ul` element that contains `li` elements that are inline-block displayed. The `ul` element is centered within a `div` element. The `li` elements can wrap (depending on the number of them and the width of the `div`).

I want the width of the `ul` element to be wide enough to hold its children so that **it** centers within **its** parent. It works if there aren't enough `li` elements such that there is no need to wrap, but not if they do.

I want it to look like:
[image]

But it looks like:
[image]

```css
div {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid 1px green;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>    
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>    
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions on getting this to work.

Comment: Do you mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/jg469u36/3/

Comment: Not sure about what exactly you're looking for, but you could [give `white-space: nowrap;` to the unordered list](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/jg469u36/2/) to make the list items stay beside each other in lower widths.

Comment: Not clear. Put text-align:center on the ul like @Paulie_D indicates

Comment: @Paulie_D - I want the li elements to remain left-aligned.

Comment: @HashemQolami I'm afraid your example no longer wraps the li elements

Comment: I've added images of what I want it to look like and what it actually looks like.

Comment: Pretty sure the box model doesn't let you do that. Perhaps with JS but it might look a little funky. Maybe flexbox but even then I'm not sure.